# Euler Circuit contains a circuit

Tags: graph-theory

A graph contains a circuit(closed trail), which contains every edge of the graph an odd number of times.  Does it follow that G contains an Euler-circuit as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add the additional requirement that our graph be connected, because otherwise graphs containing isolated vertices are an obvious counterexample.  I will also focus my attention on simple graphs, not on multigraphs, in order to avoid possible confusion caused by loops.

Approach via contradiction.

Suppose that it wasn't Eulerian but still happened to have such a circuit that used every edge an odd number of times.  Since the single circuit passes every edge and every vertex has at least one incident edge, it follows that the graph is connected.

Since we know the graph is connected yet by assumption is not Eulerian, then there must be some vertex which is of odd degree (*see proof for why a connected graph is Eulerian iff every vertex is of even degree*).  Assume without loss of generality that this vertex is not the "start" of the circuit (*this is just to avoid having to rewrite the following argument a second time*).

Count how many times edges incident to that vertex are used and total them together.  If every edge incident to it was used an odd number of times, then there will have been an odd number of times its incident adjacent edges were used in total since its degree is odd.  $\underline{\text{However, this is a contradiction}}$ since every time the incident edges are used there is an edge going *to* our vertex followed by an edge going *from* our vertex, so the edges are used in pairs and should have caused the incident edges to total an *even* number of uses, not an odd number.

Therefore, yes.  If a simple graph with no isolated vertices (*or equivalently a simple connected graph*) has a closed circuit which uses each edge an odd number of times, then it must be Eulerian.